# Make sliding window (size MxN) without nfilter function to do local and adaptive operation like local thresholding?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, window

I need a matlab code to make `MxN` sliding window without `nfilter()` function to do adaptive and local operation like adaptive threshold.

For example, I want to implement **OTSU's thresholding method** `graythresh()` in each **rectangle** (MxN window) not *pixel* to *pixel*.

I wrote this code but it has some problem:

```
im=imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(im);figure,title('original image')
M=64; %lenght of window
N=64; %width of widow
[row,col]=size(im);
out=zeros(M,N);
out1=zeros(row,N);

for i=1:N:row
     for j=1:M:col
         mask=im(i:i+N-1,j:j+M-1);
         bw=im2bw(mask,graythresh(mask));
         out=[out,bw];imshow(out),title('output')
     end
%      out1=[out1;out];
%      out=zeros(M,N);
end
% figure,imshow(out1)
```

input image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0EZo.png

output image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmP9j.png

Comment: Are you allowed to use `im2col`?  What about `colfilt`? `blockproc`? `imfilter`?  If you convolve your image with an average mask, that's essentially computing the mean of the local neighbourhoods.  Let me know what other functions you can't use and I'll write an answer.

Comment: dear @rayryeng thanks for your answer. I can't use  _nfilter()_  cuz I use matlab-2012b and this version doesn't have this function, fortunately I have all other functions you mentioned.

Comment: I think I couldn't ask vivid question to give answer which I want.
I'll edit my question soon.

Comment: How do you apply Otsu on a window? It's a pixel operation. You find the best global threshold that maximizes class separability and then threshold each pixel. You need to be more clear as I don't understand you.

Comment: OK so you want to apply Otsu on each neighborhood? Find the optimum threshold for each neighborhood and threshold within that neighborhood?

Comment: dear @rayryeng thanks alot for your answers and kind advise, I added an answer, please check it and correct it. I do appreciate you for what you have done for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete rewrite of my original post as I now know what you're trying to do.  Your code does work in that you want to extract `M x N` **distinct** neighbourhoods, perform Otsu's algorithm on each neighbourhood, then set these neighbourhoods to an output image.

However, you are not constructing the final image properly.  You are stacking the neighbourhoods column-wise but what you need to do you need to move down to the next rows once you reach the end column of the image.  To get your code working, the easiest thing would be to have another matrix that you create within the loop that goes over the columns and when you get to the end, concatenate this matrix to the output image row-wise.  I've removed some fluff from your code to get to my point quickly:

```
im=imread('cameraman.tif');
M=64; %//height of window
N=64; %//width of widow
[row,col]=size(im);
out = []; %// Create output image

for i=1:N:row
     out1 = []; %// Inner matrix
     for j=1:M:col
         mask=im(i:i+N-1,j:j+M-1);
         bw=im2bw(mask,graythresh(mask));
         out1 = [out1 bw]; %// Concatenate column-wise
     end
     out = [out; out1]; %// Take inner matrix and concatenate row-wise
end
figure; subplot(1,2,1); imshow(im); title('Original Image');
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(out); title('Thresholded Image');
```

I'm placing the original image and thresholded image in the same figure, and we get:

[image]

---

However, because in your comments above you mentioned that you have [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) available, I would recommend you use that to minimize how much code you write.  `blockproc` allows you to process distinct pixel neighbourhoods in an image.  With each pixel neighbourhood, you can do whatever you want to them.  In our case, we want to apply Otsu's algorithm to each block and threshold it.  You can very much achieve the above resulting code in one line:

```
out = blockproc(im, [64 64], @(x) im2bw(x.data, graythresh(x.data)));
```

`im` would be the input image and `out` would be the output image.  The second parameter tells you how big each block is and the third function is a custom function you write that is applied to each block.  The input into this function is a structure where `data` is a structure element that gives you a block in an image.  Therefore, you would use `im2bw` and `graythresh` in the same method like you did above, but you would do this with the `data` field.

---

To go one more step further, you said you also have [`colfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) available which does the same thing above as `blockproc` but it reshapes the image so that the neighbourhood blocks are placed into columns, applies the function to each column then reconstructs the image back to its original dimensions.

As such:

```
out = colfilt(im, [64 64], 'distinct', @(x) im2bw(x, graythresh(x)));
```

You can see that the above syntax is almost the same as `blockproc`, but here we must specify the `'distinct'` flag to tell `colfilt` that we want distinct neighbourhoods, and not overlapping ones.  Also, it is known that `colfilt` is faster than `blockproc` (consult the documentation on `colfilt` - link above).

Comment: dear @rayryeng I think this Functions you mentioned implement pixel by pixel, as I edited my question, I want MxN window like new picture I uploaded.